# Laravel return include partitial into controller

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have made a partial for a button, now i made a lister with Datatables. You can add a column, in my example its a edit button.

Is it possible to return a patitial include into a controller?

```
return Datatables::queryBuilder($query)
          ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
              return include('partitials.button', [
                  'class'=>'btn btn-default',
              ]);
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "partial" is just a blade view. There is nothing special about it. You can render the view you need to get the evaluated string.

```
return Datatables::queryBuilder($query)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
        return view('partitials.button', ['class'=>'btn btn-default'])->render();
    })
```

Comment: Thnx! Works great :))